# How to process the response from an API, before the response is read by UICollection Datasource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have an endpoint, say: "http://somthing.com/api/ios".
I am fetching JSON from this endpoint.

I am calling the API in `viewWillAppear` method.

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
                .responseJSON { response in

                    if let JSON = response.result.value
                    {
                        self.receiveData = JSON as! [String : AnyObject]

                    }
            }
}
```

Here I am dumping the data in local variable.

And this is `UICollectionView` datasource which breaks because `receiveData` is empty or some other problem is there.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch collectionView.tag
    {
    case 0:
        return (receiveData["x"]?.count)!
    case 1:
        return (receiveData["y"]?.count)!
    case 2:
        return (receiveData["z"]?.count)!
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

I am suspecting the collectionView datasource gets called first, before `receiveData` gets populated.

Can someone tell where am I going wrong or is there any other workaround?

EDIT 1:
Attaching the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Actually my collection view is in a tablview cell. Instead of reloading the collection view, I reload the tablview where you mentioned and call the collectionview.reloadData() in willDisplayCell method. Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reload your collection view after you receive the data.

Assuming `collectionView` is the name of your collectionView, just add `self.collectionView.reloadData()` after your `if` block.

Comment: I am still stuck.
Could you please check my comment on question and see the attached screenshot in the question.

Comment: I can't see the error message in the screenshot. Can you post the exact error message that you are getting in the console?

Comment: I am not getting anything in the console, but you can see in the following image that breaks where receiveData is being parsed :
http://i.stack.imgur.com/N51EP.png

Comment: Might be because the value of `recieveData["x"]` is nil, so `recieveData["x"]?.count` will crash. Try printing `recieveData["x"]` before returning the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113905/discussion-between-ketul-patani-and-ebby94).

Comment: Thank you is working perfectly now! I am using swift 4

Answer (score 4):

You need to reload the UICollectionView after getting the response and assigning in receiveData.

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(true)

  Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
                .responseJSON { response in

                    if let JSON = response.result.value
                    {
                        self.receiveData = JSON as! [String : AnyObject]
                    }
               //Add this line
               self.collectionView.reloadData()

            }
  }
```

Comment: Actually my collection view is in a tablview cell.
Instead of reloading the collection view, I reload the tablview  where you mentioned and 
call the collectionview.reloadData() in **willDisplayCell** method.
Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: you need to reload the tableView after the if method in viewWillAppear method and reload the collectionView inside the tableview method i.e inside this method:->                                                                                     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{}

Comment: I did as you said, still getting the same error.
I have attached the screenshot in the question description, have a look.